# Выравнивание строк разной длины по центру

Tags: c, строки

Доброго вечера.

Есть 3 строки, которые расположены по центру экрана, но начинаются с четко заданной позиции (одной и той же по оси Y).
Задачка такова, что нужно заполнить определенным количеством пробелов слева, чтобы все строки (учитывая их длину) были по центру.

Пример строк:

```
This is string 1 text so long
This is string 2 short
This very short
```

Т.е. они так и располагаются на экране.
А нужно сделать, чтобы они в зависимости от своей длины выглядели вот так в результате:

```
This is string 1 text so long
    This is string 2 short
        This very short
```

На языке С.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто перед каждой строкой нужно вывести немного пробелов. Количество пробелов определяется так - (длина максимальной строки минус длина текущей строки) / 2.

Да, в том случае, если строки имеют разную четность длины, красиво выровнять не получится.

Для расчета длины можно использовать функцию strlen, поиск максимально длинной строки - это простая задача.

Для вывода можно использовать printf, у него можно задать, сколько символов отвести под поле. Но не все знают, что можно задать не только статически, но и динамически. Для этого нужно использовать звездочку.

Пусть mm - длина максимальной строки, s - текущая строка.

```
int len = strlen(s);
int ww = (mm - len) / 2 + len; /* это же (mm + len) / 2; */
printf('%*s\n', ww, s);
```